# MonoTouch--Add Button At End of Dynamically Changing Table

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I am interested in adding a button at the ending of a dynamically changing table.  The table has cells added to it on button click, but I'd like the button to only be visible once the bottom of the table is scrolled to.  I'm interest to hear if there are any ideas on how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about making `UIView` with `UIButton` and place it in `FooterView`?

```cs
tableView.TableFooterView = MyView;
```

---

Other solution is to add `UITableViewCell` with button after data cells. This should be done by `UITableViewSource`. It's nice to move all logic with last cell to abstract class, which will handle last cell functionality.

Make your own **abstract** subclass of `UITableViewSource` (name it `UITableViewSourceWithFooter`), which will contain:

- `UITableViewCell` with button;
- Method `bool IsLastCellIndexPath(NSIndexPath ip)`, which return true if `last cell` should be visible for `NSIndexPath` parameter. The code:

```cs
    protected bool IsLastCellIndexPath(NSIndexPath ip)
    {
        return ip.Row == GetRecordsCount();
    }
```

- Abstract methods `GetRecordsCount()`,
- `RowsInSection` method. `Sealed` to avoid overriding in subclasses. They will implement `GetRecordsCount()` method instead:

```cs
    public sealed override int RowsInSection (UITableView tableview, int section)
    {
        return GetRecordsCount() + 1;
    }
```

then implement and use subclass of `UITableViewSourceWithFooter`:

- In `GetCell` make some logic:

```cs
   if (base.IsLastCellIndexPath(indexPath) {
       return base.cell_with_button;
   } else {
       return data_cell;
   }
```

- Method `GetRecordsCount()`. In simple, it will be like:

```cs
     List<item_class> items;
     ...
     protected override GetRecordsCount()
     {
         return items.Count;
     }
```

Comment: Thanks, this has to be one of the best answers I've ever Received on StackOverflow!!